# Display invalid procedures and packages for each user

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, compilation, package

I have around 30 users in Oracle.

I want to see the schema for each procedure or package that has compilation errors. Is there some table or view which can me show that? I don't want to check each one manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a way to find the invalid objects:

```
select *
from dba_objects
where status = 'INVALID'
```

This will even give views, synonyms, ..., but you can easily filter the result by the `OBJECT_TYPE` column, like

```
WHERE object_type in ('PACKAGE BODY', 'PROCEDURE', ...)
```

You may want (or need) to edit `DBA_OBJECTS` into `ALL_OBJECTS`, depending on your needs and privileges; [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/DBA_OBJECTS.html#GUID-4EB0E78C-EA23-4D7B-98F2-D0583C7C1F62) is something more.